# nextjs server side rendering with geolocation data from client side

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering

Earlier I was facing problem with SEO with pure ReactJS so I am now changing to NextJS.

My requirements are I need to dynamically generate SEO for example **There are [500 plumbers] around [New York City]**, where the **[500 plumbers]** is based on user selection and **[New York City]** is based on the user current location state.

If I dynamically render during client side, the SEO did not pick up so I have to render from server side, but the location can only be capture during client side so I have to somehow store the location, save into server side and refresh the page.

I have attached my sample codes as below for references:

1. First I will get client location using the `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` (line 11)
2. Then I would like to save the location data into server side (line 22)
3. Then..??

[image]

Comment: Does user selection means there is a list of choices a user can make? If yes, you can pre-generate pages for all those choices for SEO

Comment: @RobinThomas the user selection is basically a Google Map marker for user to pin point his location, it is not feasible to pre-generate all the locations as pages for the SEO.

Comment: If you recognise its a crawler bot, use a pre-generated page from the server with some dummy location. Shouldnt that work?